# Drupal: How to Remove/Redirect node listing page

Tags: drupal, drupal-nodes

I recently launched a Drupal site and noticed, after looking through my admin logs, that there existed a page in which a summary of every node on my page could be viewed. I found that this page was accessible at [mysitename]/node?page=1 and showed a list of all nodes in my site with a paginator at the bottom.

I've never run into this before and I'm unsure how to remove or re-direct from this page. It doesn't seem to be coming from a view or a panel, and I've never encountered this issue before, so I'm at a loss as to what's creating this page.

Here's an example of what I'd like to disable:: http://drupal.org/node?page=1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515110/disabling-node-view-and-other-hidden-views-in-drupal/1515373#1515373 for an existing, simple but developer-centric answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/node` only shows pages with the "promoted to front page" option ticked. If you don't use that, it should be empty.

One way you could do it would be using Views; you could override `/node` to display something else ("Sorry, I don't feel like letting you do that today.").

Also searching the web for "drupal disable node" finds some useful stuff - e.g. http://groups.drupal.org/node/32704. That page has a variety of good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do what Chris Morgan suggested and also, to prevent double content issues with Google and other search engines, use .htaccess or robots.txt to prevent anyone to enter /node.